# Get XYZ rotation from PVector

Tags: java, 3d, angle

I have a normalized `PVector` that represents a direction from the origin:

```
PVector dir = new PVector(-0.1, 0.8, 0.3);
```

I'd like to get the X, Y, and Z angles in that direction, so I can use the `rotateX()`, etc matrix transformations.

In 2D, I'd use `atan2()` to get the angle, but I have no idea how to do this for a 3D point.

Comment: I'll add, there are quite a few questions about Euler angles and things that seem related, but not sure if any of that applies to getting XYZ angles?

Comment: Use a dot product between the vector and the axes

Comment: @ifly6 – Can you post some code as an answer? My vector math is... terrible.

Comment: Well, I'm writing it now

Answer (score 2):

The way I find the angle with the axes is using the dot product. My vectors are all called `GravVector`, mostly because I use it in gravitational n-body simulations. My implementation of the vector has methods like `.magnitude()` to easily return the magnitude of the vector, something you will need.

The [dot product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dot_product) is basically multiplying across the vector X, Y, and Z values, and then summing all those products. For three dimensions, this can be written explicitly like so:

```
public double dotProduct(GravVector vector) {
    return this.x * vector.x + this.y * vector.y + this.z * vector.z;
}
```

Now, the dot product has a nice characteristic where the product is equivalent to the magnitudes of the two vectors multiplied by the cosine of the angle between those two vectors. That, when shifted around, becomes this:

[image: Latex is the best formatting.]

This means that to find the angle, you can simply arccosine the value of the right side.

My code does this below, yielding the `double`s with `angleX`, `angleY`, and `angleZ`. Please note that the result is in radians. If you want this in degrees, you need to multiply whatever it is you have in radians by `180 / Math.PI`.

```
GravVector vector = new GravVector(1, 1, 0);

// magnitude * 1 because the magnitude of the temporary vector is 1.
double angleX = Math.acos(vector.dotProduct(new GravVector(1, 0, 0)) / (vector.magnitude() * 1));
double angleY = Math.acos(vector.dotProduct(new GravVector(0, 1, 0)) / (vector.magnitude() * 1));
double angleZ = Math.acos(vector.dotProduct(new GravVector(0, 0, 1)) / (vector.magnitude() * 1));

// in radians
System.out.println(String.format("x: %.2f, y: %.2f, z: %.2f",
        angleX, angleY, angleZ));

// in degrees
System.out.println(String.format("x: %.2f, y: %.2f, z: %.2f",
        angleX * 180 / Math.PI,
        angleY * 180 / Math.PI, 
        angleZ * 180 / Math.PI));
```

The output to the console that is printed out is, the first line being in radians, the second line being in degrees:

```
x: 0.79, y: 0.79, z: 1.57
x: 45.00, y: 45.00, z: 90.00
```

You could easily generalise this to get the angle between any two vectors (it does not matter if they are of unit magnitude or not) like so:

```
public static double angleBetween(GravVector v1, GravVector v2) {
    return Math.acos(v1.dotProduct(v2) / (v1.magnitude() * v2.magnitude())); 
    // in radians
}
```

---

**EDIT.** Consider that with respect to any one of the axes, the dot product will always be equivalent to the relevant component. Thus, for the X axis, it will just be the X component.

This means that you can simplify the calculations and have methods like this:

```
public static double xAngle(GravVector vector) {
    return Math.acos(vector.x / (vector.magnitude()));
}

public static double yAngle(GravVector vector) {
    return Math.acos(vector.y / (vector.magnitude()));
}

public static double zAngle(GravVector vector) {
    return Math.acos(vector.z / (vector.magnitude()));
}
```

For the example vector, with components of [1, 1, 0], if you called and printed the values for each of these methods, it would result with the following, which are consistent with the above values:

```
x, rad: 0.7853981633974484
y, rad: 0.7853981633974484
z, rad: 1.5707963267948966
```

Answer (score 0):

Not 100% sure if I understood what you mean by x, y, z angles, but I think you mean, in the case of the "z angle", to use your words, the angle that is needed to rotate a vector with origin (0, 0, 0) and end where Z is 0 and it goes along the X or Y axis (that would be your choice), to rotate it around the Z axis so that the resulting vector is the projection of the original vector on the X,Y plane, projection which incidentally is simply (x, y, 0).

That angle around Z would be the arc tangent of y/x or (x/y).

Do the same for X axis and Y axis and you have those three rotation angles. You only need two of them and an initial vector, but I don't know if that's relevant to the problem.